# Enabling virtualization in Win 8.1 Gridview with Grouping

Tags: gridview, windows-8.1, ui-virtualization

I have been trying to reduce the load time of a page that contains this gridview, As per MS documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx ,you will not get virualization if you use Grouping. Does anyone knows how to do this?

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="serviceViewSource" Source="{Binding PageData}" IsSourceGrouped="True" ItemsPath="Contents" />


<GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
        TabIndex="1"
        Padding="120,0,0,50"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource serviceViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        IsSwipeEnabled="True"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsGridViewEnabled}"
        CanReorderItems="False" CanDragItems="False" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True"
        common:GridViewItemClickedCommand.Command="{Binding ItemClickedCommand}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource gridViewTemplateSelector}"
        >

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="headerGrid">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="headerButton" Content='{Binding Name}' Background="Transparent" Foreground="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.HeaderCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"

                                       IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" CommandParameter="{Binding HeaderIdentifier}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" />
                                <ProgressRing Grid.Column="1" IsActive="{Binding LoadingData}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">

                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>

                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>

                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="0,0,80,0">

                            </VariableSizedWrapGrid>

                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </GridView.GroupStyle>
        </GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 8.1 using the `GridView` with defaults will use the `ItemsWrapGrid` as the panel and this does group virtualization for you.  Using a `StackPanel` as you have your code will not get UI virtualized.

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out, this was the line in documentation which was throwing me off. "UI virtualization is not supported for grouped data. For more info about grouping data, see How to group items in a list or grid" but the video at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-158 cleared it up for me. Now I am stuck with layout cycle error detected though :-|